# Neo4j insert nodes with various relationships

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, performance, neo4j

I tried to create "recipe", "ingredients" and "user" nodes (author).

Basically, an author can have many recipes; and recipes have a many-to-many relationship with ingredients.

I have this query:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE ID(user) = {uid}
CREATE (recipe:Recipe {name:"receta 4"})
WITH ingredient
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE ID(ingredient) = node(7)
CREATE (recipe)-[ri:HAS {unit: "vasos", cant: 1}]-(ingredient)
WITH ingredient
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE ID(ingredient) = node(6)
CREATE (recipe)-[ri:HAS {unit: "cditas", cant: 2}]-(ingredient)
CREATE (user)-[:PREPARE]->(recipe)
RETURN recipe
```

But, i get error:

```
ingredient not defined (line 4, column 7)
"WITH (ingredient:Ingredient)"
       ^
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

Which is the correct form for this query?

My js code:

```
Recipe.create = function (req, callback) {

    var data = req.body;
    var uid = parseInt(req.params.id);

    var query = [
        'MATCH (user:User)',
        'WHERE ID(user) = {uid}',
        'CREATE (recipe:Recipe {data})',
    ];

    // set ingredients
    var ingId;
    var unit;
    var cant;
    for (var i = data.ingredients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ing   = data.ingredients[i];
        ingId = parseInt(ing.id);
        unit  = ing.unit;
        cant  = ing.cant;
        query.push(
            'MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)',
            'WHERE ID(ingredient) = node(' + ingId + ')',
            'CREATE (recipe)-[ri:HAS {unit: "'+unit+'", cant: '+cant+'}]-(ingredient)'
        );    
    }

    query.push(
        'CREATE (user)-[:PREPARE]->(recipe)',
        'RETURN recipe'
    );

    query.join("\n");

    db.cypher({
        query:query, 
        params:{
            data: data,
            uid: uid
        }
    }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        console.log(results)
        callback(null, results);            
    });
};
```

Comment: @HoaParis thanks! I'm speak spanish :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the WITH clause referencing the next node to be created, rather than referencing the previous node to be created. Additionally, the code is trying to create undirected relationships.

Try this:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE ID(user) = {uid}
CREATE (recipe:Recipe {name:"receta 4"})
WITH recipe
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE id(ingredient) = 7
CREATE (recipe)-[ri:HAS {unit: "vasos", cant: 1}]->(ingredient)
WITH recipe
MATCH (ingredient:Ingredient)
WHERE ID(ingredient) = 6
CREATE (recipe)-[ri:HAS {unit: "cditas", cant: 2}]->(ingredient)
CREATE (user)-[:PREPARE]->(recipe)
RETURN recipe
```

Comment: Yes, the recipe relation <-> ingredient is undirected, because some queries search is for an ingredient get all recipes.

Comment: Undirected isn't supported when CREATing (you'll see an error).  You can either create relationships in both directions, or you can query without directionality when you do your MATCH queries in the future.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010932/neo4j-bidirectional-relationship

Comment: MERGE supports not specifying a relationship direction, if it already finds a rel it will use that, otherwise it will create from left to right.