# How to get a 'specific grade' relation using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

We are getting started in Graph databases, and I don't understand how to make a select query where I need to select ***5th grade friends of a user foo@hmail.com***.

Also I wanted to know if there is some kind of tutorial for this kind of query, because I didn't find one.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and show what your effort so far. Do you try to find it in stackoverflow ,such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743996/neo4j-find-degree-of-connection

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n:User {Name:"foo@hmail.com"})-[:friends]->(a)-[:IN_GRADE]->(g)
WHERE g.grade = 5
RETURN a.Name
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Best place to learn : 
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/introduction/