# Create Bi-directional relation between two vertices using OpenCypher with Apache AGE

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

In the below example I create a one-direction relation between two vertices (from b to a), is there a way I can create a relation from (a to b) at the same time?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cypher('test_graph', $$
    MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person) WHERE a.name = 'hossam' AND b.name = 'omar'
    CREATE (b)-[r:REL {name: b.name+'->'+a.name}]->(a) RETURN r
$$) as (v agtype);
```

I tried remove the arrow symbol **>** before **(a)** like:  `CREATE (b)-[r:REL {name: b.name+'->'+a.name}]-(a)` but it results with a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now i believe the most straightforward way to achieve bidirectional relations is to set it as a property, you can't just remove the  direction at the moment of creation. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)
WHERE a.name = "hossam" AND b.name = "omar"
CREATE (a)-[e:FRIENDS]-(b)
RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
```

this will return as you said the error

```
ERROR:  only directed relationships are allowed in CREATE
LINE 4: CREATE (a)-[e:FRIENDS]-(b)
```

and the same thing will happen if you use bidirectional edge

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)
WHERE a.name = "hossam" AND b.name = "omar"
CREATE (a)<-[e:FRIENDS]->(b)
RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 4: CREATE (a)<-[e:BORDERS_WITH]->(b)
```

You need to try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('graph', $$
MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person)
WHERE a.name = "hossam" AND b.name = "omar"
CREATE (a)-[e:FRIENDS{ type:"<->" }]->(b)
RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
```

by assigning the "<->" as properties you can search search all the bidirectional relations in your graph using:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('graph', $$
MATCH (a)-[e:FRIENDS]->(b)
WHERE e.type = "<->"
RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
```

Since the feature of bidirectional relations isn't yet supported I believe this is one way to get around that.

Answer (score 2):

**Create two relations in one go:**

```sql
SELECT *                                                                      
FROM cypher('test', $$
    MATCH (a:Person), (b:Person) WHERE a.name = 'hossam' AND b.name = 'omar'
    CREATE br =
    (b)-[r:REL {name: b.name+'->'+a.name}]->(a)<-[r:REL {name: b.name+'<-'+a.name}]-(b)
    RETURN br
$$) as (v agtype);
```

---

AGE ensures your graphs have a bi-directional relationship in terms of Edges.

Try the following query to check:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('test_graph', $$ MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) RETURN r $$) as (v agtype);
```

Returns:

```
 {"id": 9570149208162308, "label": "REL", "end_id": 9851624184872964, "start_id": 9851624184872963, "pro
perties": {"name": "omar->hossam"}}::edge
```

The query for the opposite relation match

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('test_graph', $$ MATCH (b)-[r]->(a) RETURN r $$) as (v agtype);
```

Returns:

```
 {"id": 9570149208162308, "label": "REL", "end_id": 9851624184872964, "start_id": 9851624184872963, "pro
perties": {"name": "omar->hossam"}}::edge
```

If however you need the relation to be in the form of `hossam->omar`. You'll need to define another relation, preferably from `(a)-[r]->(b)`. And it will show up as another edge.

OR,

<s>A better approach is to just imply the relation as the following `b.name+'<->'+a.name`</s>

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to create bidirectional relationships in Apache AGE.
There is no way to create bidirectional relationships in Neo4j either as written in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010932/neo4j-bidirectional-relationship). The reasoning being since you are allowed to make non-directional queries, bidirectional relationships become essentially same as disregarding the direction altogether.

On a more technical level:-

The edges are stored with a vertex start_id and an end_id in the edges table. Having bidirectional relationship means that both the start_id and the end_id need to have 2 values.

You have 2 alternatives:-

1.) Make another relationship in the opposite direction (however it takes more space).

2.) Make non-directional queries.